# How to get the Model property value in View page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view page, where I want to do multiplication operation with the value of model property with a local variable.

### View.cshtml :

```
@model FLIPCART.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 <div> @Model.CartTotal  </div>

<select>
   @for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
      {
         <option value="@i">@i</option>
       }
       </select>
```

Can it operate like this `var result=(@Model.CartTotal * @i)` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
<div> @(Model.CartTotal * i)  </div>
```

if you want in some variable then:

```
    @{

    var result=Model.CartTotal *i

    }

<div> @result  </div>
```

in this way `var result=(@Model.CartTotal * @i)`   asterik will be interpreted as string